# How to expose and serve WOFF file from Azure without web.config?

Tags: angular, azure, static-content, woff

I'm serving a static site (really Angular but all the bundles are static as well as the *index-html*) in Azure. It works as supposed to except a single thing. For some reason the WOFF files aren't being exposed properly.

The solution for it as far my google-foo goes is to edit the *web.config* in a way similar to [this blog](http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/WOFF_files_return_404_in_Azure_Web_Sites) or [this one](http://blog.iqit.dk/2013/11/configuring-a-nodejs-website-on-azure) and a similar suggestions are all over the place.

Here's the tricky part: I don't have a *config* in my deployment. It's just a bunch of files (a few HTMLs, JSs and CSSs - and the darn WOFF). How can I make Azure application serve **all** static content, including WOFFs?

Comment: Please be more specific on which Azure service did you use for hosting your site - Azure App Service\Azure Storage\Azure VM?

Comment: @itaysk Sorry, didn't realize the significance. Azure App Service. I created a service using web client. Then cloned a BitBucket project and set it up as Static.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> I don't have a config in my deployment

You can just add a *web.config* file at the root folder of your app with the following contents.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" /> 
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Oh, that simple? I've read in one of the blogs that doing so will override the *web.config* created for me automagically by Azure. It was claimed that there's one provided by default if none is uploaded to the server. Perhaps I was mistaken?

Comment: Confirmed now - your suggestion works (I've taken the liberty to complete it with the contents for future, lazy readers). Now, my issue is that the file is removed from the *dist* directory upon a build but that's material for another question.

Comment: @KonradViltersten you can add the *web.config* file into assets configuration of the angular build:  ```"assets": ["src/assets", "src/favicon.ico", "src/web.config"]``` and it will get included in your dist folder

Answer (score 2):

You can install an extension for your Azure App Service:

https://github.com/johnnyqian/enable-font-awesome-site-extension